# Fix a regex to exclude false results

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm writing a file parser...
I have this string

```
line = "E-Cluster HW active residency:  57.25% (600 MHz:   0% 972 MHz:  32% 1332 MHz: 6.8% 1704 MHz:  11% 2064 MHz:  50%)\n"

line.gsub(/[^\d.]/,'')
=> "57.2560009723213326.8170411206450"

line.match(/:\s+(\d+)/)[1]
=> "57"
```

I need '57.25'

How can I fix it?

Comment: `\d` digit really only means 0-9 you have to include an optional `.` followed by at least 1 digit again. soemthing like `/:\s+(\d+)/([.|,]\d+)?`

Comment: Hi Roberto, do you just want to extract the first number?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
line = "E-Cluster HW active residency:  57.25% (600 MHz:   0% 972 MHz:  32% 1332 MHz: 6.8% 1704 MHz:  11% 2064 MHz:  50%)\n"

line.gsub(/[^\d.]+/,'').match(/\d+\.\d{1,2}/)[0]
=> "57.25"
```

A `match` with regex `/\d+\.\d{2}/` gets you string up to 1 or 2 decimal points only.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the first number with

```rb
line = "E-Cluster HW active residency:  57.25% (600 MHz:   0% 972 MHz:  32% 1332 MHz: 6.8% 1704 MHz:  11% 2064 MHz:  50%)\n"
line[/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/]
=> "57.25"
```

See [Ruby code proof](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/PyczL1XBVkHJVdc5p7S4JLVIwSNcITG5JLMsVaEotTgzJTUvudJKQcHUXM/IVFVBw8zAQMHXowooomCgqmBpbgTlGRupKhgaG0O5ZnoWQK65gQlU1tBQVcHIwAzGNTVQ1YzJU@IqKC0pVgC5IFo/JkVbw94qRg9Ia9rrx/7/DwA).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
```